# Using href in html

Tags: html, css, href

I have been asked to copy the font awesome link and paste it into the head area of the HTML : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />` I need to place this above the link to the index.css file.

This is the code that I have already been given:

```
<html>

  <head>

 <meta charset="utf-8">

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<title>repl.it</title>

<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

 </head>
```

Below is where I have added the href and the <link rel="stylesheet" but it doesn't accept it so not sure where I have gone wrong. I have left a space between where I have added the code, please let me know your thoughts, thanks.

```
<html>

<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

 <title>repl.it</title>


   <link href:"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css"/> 

 <link rel="stylesheet/>



  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  
</head>
```

Comment: You were given the code to add to your document (as in the question), when you copied it to your document why did you - apparently - change it from the correct format `href="https://..."` to `href:"https://...`?

Comment: Just to note: there is a missing `"` double quote in `rel="stylesheet/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css">
```